# How to install Anaconda on External Hard drive?

Tags: install, python

I have the Apple Silicon Macbook Air with 256 GB, and am interested in installing Anaconda mainly Jupyter notebook in my Mac. When I tried installing it on my external Hard drive, which is a 1TB SSD, I got an error(Cannot be installed in /Volumes/SATA SSD/anaconda because the path contains spaces). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: I did look into it and found it was a name error on my Storage Disk.

Comment: Great.  But do post the message next time, if you can. People can more easily help you.  Welcome aboard.

Answer (score 2):

If the error is about the space, then if the Volume (External Hard disk) is made without spaces it gets rectified. For example, in my case it was "SATA SSD", once modified into "SATA_SSD" anaconda was installed.

Comment: If hard drive space usage is your concern, you could look into installing [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). Also, look into [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba), which is a faster conda solver.

Comment: Ah yes, Apple’s insistence to have spaces everywhere, but then the terminal and other stuff choke on it. +1 for posting fix, maybe save someone some time in future.

Comment: @JLPeyret This is not Apple's problem - they have had spaces since the early 1980s nor Unix's issue the file systems can deal with spaces - it is the design of shells making a space a special character. Compare most programming languages which require " or '

Comment: @mmmmmm We'll agree to disagree.  A number of OSs, Windows and Macos come to mind, have decided to have some of their internal system folders include spaces.  That didn't have to be done, and the added value of `Library/Application Support` vs `Library/ApplicationSupport` seems limited, especially considering how little end users usually see those directories directly.  But now that they have done that you need to jump through shell spaces-handling hoops every time you interact with them.  For example, if I pass in `Library/Application Support` as a parameter to a command, it'll assume 2 param

Comment: True - the classic macOS and Windows way is not to use a command but write a small GUI app so spaces are part of an input field - or use a shell that makes argumentes in "" The problem is most Unix shells not the OS